# Scala type deferring

Tags: scala, playframework-2.0

I am using Play framework 2.1 and Scala 2.10.1 and would like to build a general function to construct a JsArray out of a List of custom case class.

```
private def buildJsArray[T](l: List[T])(result: JsArray): JsArray = {
    l match {
      case List() => result
      case x::xs => buildJsArray(xs)(result :+ Json.toJson(x)) // compiling error here!
    }
  }
```

usage:

```
val applyJsonArray = buildJsArray(List[Apple])(new JsArray())
```

However, a compiling error is thrown:

> ```
> No Json deserializer found for type T. Try to implement an implicit Writes or Format for this 
>  type.
> ```

I do have a Json deserializer written for the particular case class(i.e., Apple case class).

How do I defer the compiler to check the type of x in runtime rather than in compile time?

Many Thanks!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

**How to fix a error**

You have to add an [implicit parameter](http://www.artima.com/pins1ed/implicit-conversions-and-parameters.html) to your method like this:

```
def buildJsArray[T](l: List[T])(result: JsArray)(implicit tjs: Writes[T]): JsArray
```

There is such parameter in the [`Json.toJson`](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/api/2.0/scala/index.html#play.api.libs.json.Json$) method.

The reason why you have to add this parameter is that you know how to convert `T` to `json` only when you know what `T` is. It means you have the method to serialize `T` only when you call `buildJsArray` and this parameter allows you to pass this serialization method to the method `buildJsArray`.

**How to build a JSArray**

You could just use a constructor of [`JsArray`](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/api/2.0/scala/index.html#play.api.libs.json.JsArray). It takes a `Seq[JsValue]`:

```
new JsArray(l.map{Json.toJson(_)})
```

There is already an [implicit `Writes`](https://github.com/playframework/Play20/blob/master/framework/src/play-json/src/main/scala/play/api/libs/json/Writes.scala#L165) for `Traversable` so you don't need your own method `buildJsArray`, you could just use method `Json.toJson` with parameter of type `List[T]`.

**Addition**

You should take a look at the collections api. It allows you to write more readable and shorter code:

```
def buildJsArray[T](l: List[T])(implicit tjs: Writes[T]): JsArray =
  l.foldLeft(new JsArray){ (r, x) => r :+ Json.toJson(x) }
```

Comment: Perfect answer, nothing to add :)

Comment: When dealing with JsObject(s), you can't use the generic OFormat type for your implicit. You'll need to do one implicit for OWrites and one for Reads