# Scala Play 2.4 Serialize with Parameter Type

Tags: json, scala, serialization, playframework, parameterized-types

I already took a look at: [Scala type deferring](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17289493/scala-type-deferring), it looks like close to my problem but I can't resolve it with the answer, unfortunately.

So, here's the code:

My GenericModel

```
abstract class GenericModel[T] {
  val _id: Option[BSONObjectID]
  def withId(newId: BSONObjectID): T
}
```

My Implemented Model

```
case class Push
(_id: Option[BSONObjectID], text: String)
extends GenericModel[Push]
{
  override def withId(newId: BSONObjectID) = this.copy(_id = Some(newId))
}

object Push{
  implicit val pushFormat = Json.format[Push]
}
```

My DAO, using the case class

```
trait GenericDao[T <: GenericModel[T]] {

  val db: DB
  val collectionName: String

  /**
   * Inserts new object
   * @param newobject
   * @return Some(stringified bsonID) or None if error
   */
  def insert(newobject: T)(implicit tjs: Writes[T]): Future[Option[BSONObjectID]] = {
    val bsonId = BSONObjectID.generate
    val beaconWithId = newobject.withId(bsonId)
    db.collection[JSONCollection](collectionName).insert(beaconWithId).map{ lastError =>
      if(lastError.ok)
        Some(bsonId)
      else
        None
    }
  }
}
```

I got the error

```
No Json serializer as JsObject found for type T. Try to implement an implicit OWrites or OFormat for this type
```

Here, during insert method

```
db.collection[JSONCollection](collectionName).insert(beaconWithId)
```

Like I said before, I already tried with implicit Writes.
Thanks for your help, I hope that I didn't missed something on the referenced topic on the beggining.

Comment: I am actually facing nearly the same problem.. did you figure it out already?

Comment: Didn't find the solution. My insert method is in implementation DAO now and not in a Generic DAO unfortunately, like I searched for... I'm sorry

Answer (score 0):

The idea is to add `[T : Writes]`, the question is where.
You can try this :

```
trait GenericDao[T <: GenericModel[T]] {

  val db: DB
  val collectionName: String

  /**
   * Inserts new object
   * @param newobject
   * @return Some(stringified bsonID) or None if error
   */
  def insert[T : Writes](newobject: T)(implicit tjs: Writes[T]): Future[Option[BSONObjectID]] = {
    val bsonId = BSONObjectID.generate
    val beaconWithId = newobject.withId(bsonId)
    db.collection[JSONCollection](collectionName).insert(beaconWithId).map{ lastError =>
      if(lastError.ok)
        Some(bsonId)
      else
        None
    }
  }
}
```

Or perhaps this (or both) :

```
abstract class GenericModel[T : Writes] {
  val _id: Option[BSONObjectID]
  def withId(newId: BSONObjectID): T
}
```

Comment: None works. Always the same error. And if I modify T in GenericModel, then Push crash on format ...

Answer (score 0):

```
implicit val pushFormat = Json.format[Push]
```

Json.format extends Format[A] trait which in turn extends of Writes[A] and Reads[A]. So the error is right, compiler cannot find OWrites for its serialising the object.

To Solve this error instead of using Json.format[Push] extend OWrites and Reads

```
implicit object Push extends OWrites[Push] {
    def writes(push: Push): JsObject = Json.obj(
      "_id" -> push.id,
      "text" -> push.text  
    }
implicit object pushReads extends Reads[Push] {
    def reads(json: JsValue): JsResult[Push] = json match {
        case obj: JsObject => try {
            val id = (obj \ "_id").asOpt[String]
            val text = (obj \ "text").as[String] 
            JsSuccess(Push(id, text))
        } catch {
          case cause: Throwable => JsError(cause.getMessage)
        }
         case _ => JsError("expected.jsobject")
        }
}
```

And in DAO change Writes[T] to OWrites[T]

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and I had to implement a method to tell the Object how to become a JsValue:

```
def toJs[T : Writes](o: T) = Json.toJson(o).as[JsObject]
```

So the insert part of my MongoRepository looks like this:

```
trait MongoRepository[T <: MongoModel] {

lazy val db: DB = {
    import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global
    import reactivemongo.core.nodeset.Authenticate
    import scala.collection.JavaConversions._

    val driver = new MongoDriver
    val connection = driver.connection(
      config.getStringList("mongodb.servers"),
      MongoConnectionOptions(),
      Seq(Authenticate(
        config.getString("mongodb.db"),
        config.getString("mongodb.credentials.username"),
        config.getString("mongodb.credentials.password")
      )
      )
    )
    connection.db(config.getString("mongodb.db"))
  }

  def collectionName: String    
  def collection = db(collectionName)
  def ensureIndexes: Future[List[Boolean]]

  def toJs[T : Writes](o: T) = Json.toJson(o).as[JsObject]

  def insert(document: T)(implicit writer: Writes[T]): Future[Either[ServiceException, T]] = {
       document._id match {
         case None => document._id = Some(BSONObjectID.generate)
         case Some(exist) => {}
       }
       document.created = Some(DateTime.now)
       document.updated = Some(DateTime.now)
       Logger.debug(s"Inserting document: [collection=$collectionName, data=$document]")
       recoverOperation(collection.insert(toJs(document))) {
         document
       }
   }

...

}
```

Hope this helps :)